# .htaccess - Rewrite multiple subdirectories to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite multiple subdirectories to the root directory. The situation I have it that I have one folder named *blog/* which would contain the main site folder and also another subdirectory called *projects/* containing other folders which I want accessible from the root:

```
www/
    blog/
        work/
        contact/
    projects/
        projectA/
        projectB/
```

What I want, is to be able to access *work/*, *contact/*, *projectA/* and *projectB/* from the root directory by going to *example.com/projectA* or *example.com/projectB* for example. I would also like the *blog/* directory to take priority in the case that a folder exists in both.

Currently, in my htaccess, I have this, though it just rewrites everything to *blog/*, removing this from the URL, though not affecting the *projects/* folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on

# first check if request is in /blog/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]

# then check if request is in /projects/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/projects%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/projects%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/$1 [L]

# otherwise, blindly rewrite to blog (or do nothing by removing this rule to allow a 404 not found)
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked exactly as intended!